# Merge Apache Spark columns from array and struct inside struct array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is the schema of the incomming data stream. Im using spark 2.3.2 streaming to process the data.

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
            StructField("status", StringType),
            StructField("data", StructType(Seq(
                StructField("resultType", StringType),
                StructField("result", ArrayType(StructType(Array(
                    StructField("metric", StructType(Seq(StructField("application", StringType),
                                                         StructField("component", StringType),
                                                         StructField("instance", StringType)))), 
                    StructField("value", ArrayType(StringType))
                ))))
             )
         ))))
```

Here is how i've applied the schema to the dstream's rdd.

```
  val df = rdd.toDS()                        
                    .selectExpr("cast (value as string) as myData") 
                    .select(from_json($"myData", schema).as("myData"))               
                    .select($"myData.data.*")
                    .select("result")
```

The above code yields the following output

```
{"result":[{"metric":{"application":"A","component":"S","instance":"tp01.net:9072"},"value":["1.542972576979E9","237006995456"]},
       {"metric":{"application":"A","component":"S","instance":"tp02.net:9072"},"value":["1.542972576979E9","237006995456"]},
       {"metric":{"application":"A","component":"S","instance":"tp03.net:9072"},"value":["1.542972576979E9","237006995456"]},
       {"metric":{"application":"B","component":"S","instance":"bp03.net:9072"},"value":["1.542972576979E9","270860144640"]},
       {"metric":{"application":"B","component":"S","instance":"bp04.net:9072"},"value":["1.542972576979E9","270860144640"]},
       {"metric":{"application":"B","component":"S","instance":"ps01.net:9072"},"value":["1.542972576979E9","135177400320"]},
 ]}
```

But in order to extract features, i need to convert the above to the following data frame

```
application     component       instance            value1              value2
A               S               tp01.net:9072       1.542972576979E9    237006995456
A               S               tp02.net:9072       1.542972576979E9    237006995456
A               S               tp03.net:9072       1.542972576979E9    237006995456
B               S               bp03.net:9072       1.542972576979E9    270860144640
B               S               bp04.net:9072       1.542972576979E9    270860144640
B               S               ps01.net:9072       1.542972576979E9    135177400320
```

As you see the each row is already an exploded row. Any ideas on how to select the array values and the struct into a single dataframe please?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `df.select(explode($"result").as("flat")).select($"flat.metric.*", $"flat.value".getItem(0).as("value1"), $"flat.value".getItem(1).as("value2")).show()`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!